# How to animate multiple SKSpriteNode together?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, sprite-kit

I am pretty new to `SpriteKit`. I have a set of nodes that need to move together to a different point for each node and after that animation completed for all of them I would like to do something else.

I was making this with `UIView` components before. A `[UIView animateWithDuration:completion:]` block was providing the thing that I needed. But in `SpriteKit`  each node has its own action and animate by itself. I could not find any block animation for sprite nodes. So I cannot control the animation completion.

Hope, I am clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could assign and run a SKAction per node to move to a different point sequentially.. it wouldn't be at the EXACT same time but with a difference between however long it takes to execute one line of code?

Comment: Yes I am doing that right now. But I would like to do something after the animations completed for all nodes. But I could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of **SKAction** class methods that may be of interest. The first being **runBlock:** and the second being **group:** *(this allows actions to be run in parallel)*.

You can run actions on nodes with a completion handler using **runAction: completion:**

The following code puts each *'animation action'*, along with completion block in a *'block action'*. The block actions are then put into a *'group action'*. Finally the group action is told to run. This causes each block action to start at the same time. The completion handler of each block action calls a method named **checkCompletion**. This method checks for nodes *(with a specific name property value)* still animating by calling **hasActions** on the node. Because the node that called the **checkCompletion** method will return YES, if only one node returns YES then all animations are done.

The following demonstrates this using two nodes, however it will work for more than two.

```
// assuming two SKNode subclasses named 'node1' and 'node2' AND 'self' is an SKScene subclass


// assign each animating node the same name (used in checkCompletion method)
node1.name = @"animating";
node2.name = @"animating";
// in this example both nodes will animate to the origin
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
// make move actions for nodes
SKAction *shortMove = [SKAction moveTo:origin duration:1.2];
SKAction *longMove = [SKAction moveTo:origin duration:4.8];
// wrap nodes in their own separate block action
SKAction *moveNode1 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [node1 runAction:shortMove completion:^{
        NSLog(@"shortMove complete");
        [self checkCompletion];
    }];
}];
SKAction *moveNode2 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [node2 runAction:longMove completion:^{
        NSLog(@"longMove complete");
        [self checkCompletion];
    }];
}];
// put block actions in a group action
SKAction *groupAction = [SKAction group:@[moveNode1, moveNode2]];
// execute group action
[self runAction:groupAction];
```

checkCompletion method -

```
- (void)checkCompletion {

     __block int currentlyHasActions = 0;
     // check for all actions complete on animating nodes
     [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"animating" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
         if ([node hasActions]) {
             currentlyHasActions++;
             // prevent unnecessary enumeration
             if (currentlyHasActions > 1) { *stop = YES; }
         }
     }];
     if (currentlyHasActions == 1) {
         NSLog(@"Actions Finished!!!");

         // execute completion code here...

     }
}
```

Unfortunately the following will not work as a block actions duration is instantaneous. Consequently the duration of the group action in this case is also instantaneous. This is the reason for the **checkCompletion** method.

```
[self runAction:groupAction completion:^{
     // completion code here... :(
}];
```

Comment: I've implemented your solution in my own code unfortunately in some case `SKAction` never complete and completion block is not executed. Is there any side cases in this solution?

Comment: how would all of this go in swift 3? if either you want a bunch of nodes to do an action simultaneously, or sequentially, for example?